# AWS: Get Route53 HostedZone Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

im adding set of records to route53 from cloud formation and here is the code

```
 "RDSDNSRecord" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
      "Properties" : {

         "HostedZoneId" : { "Ref" : "DNSZoneId" },
         "Comment" : "DNS name for RDS",  
         "Name" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ {  "Ref": "EnvType"}, "." ,"rds",".",{"Ref" : "AWS::Region"} ,".",{"Ref" : "HostedZone"},"." ] ] },
         "Type" : "CNAME",
         "TTL" : "900",
         "ResourceRecords" : [
           {
            "Ref": "DatabaseEndPoint"
         }
         ]
      }
   }
```

and HostedZones are already created before. so in order to set these records i use these parameters.

```
"DNSZoneId":{
         "Type" :"AWS::Route53::HostedZone::Id",
         "ConstraintDescription":"must be the name of an existing ZoneId"
      },
      "HostedZone":{
         "Type": "String",
          "Description":"Relavent Domain Name"
      }
```

aws requires fully qualified domain name to be pass into parameter Name. so i asked DomainName from user along with ZoneId. I feel like asking ID and Name both is not right. is there a way to get name from zoneId or any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

`HostedZoneId` is optional, you can also use `HostedZoneName`

> [HostedZoneId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-hostedzonename) The ID of the hosted zone.
>
> Required: Conditional. You must specify either the HostedZoneName or
>   HostedZoneId, but you cannot specify both. If this record set is part
>   of a record set group, do not specify this property.

Comment: yes but there are so many hostedzones in my case hence i'm using "Type" :"AWS::Route53::HostedZone::Id" to list all the zones. i check and there is no AWS parameter type to get names or is there any way?

Comment: have you found the answer for it?